# Conditional side-effects and optional types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, side-effects

I am trying to perform a simple side-effect in Kotlin:

```
fun handle(request: Request) {
    repository.findByUID(request.userId)?.let {
        if (someCondition) return

        service.run(...)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the side-effect should be performed when the *repository* returns a non-null value and when *someCondition* is satisfied.

Is there any Kotlin-way of doing this rather than using *if{}-return* constructs?

In Java 8, it could be achieved by:

```
optional
  .filter(...)
  .ifPresent(...)
```

Comment: Use `if`s, make your core clearer :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**
[Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#takeif-and-also) has a method called `takeIf`:

```
/**
 * Returns `this` value if it satisfies the given [predicate] or `null`, if it doesn't.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
public inline fun <T> T.takeIf(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? = if (predicate(this)) this else null
```

You can use it this way:

```
repository.findByUID(request.userId)?.takeIf { someCondition }?.let { service -> }
```

---

Kotlin doesn't contain such method in the stdlib.

However, You can define it:

```
inline fun <K : Any> K.ifPresent(condition: K.() -> Boolean): K? = if (condition()) this else null
```

Using this method your example can be rewritten as:

```
fun handle(request: Request) {
    repository.findByUID(request.userId)?.ifPresent { someCondition }?.let {
        service.run(...)
    }
}
```

Another option may be to use the built in extensions for list (but there is an overhead of using lists):

```
listOf(repository.findByUID(userId)).filter { someCondition }.forEach { service.run(...) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin's [nullable types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types) are very similar to Java's [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) (which is very similar to Guava's [Optional](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)).

In Kotlin 1.1 you can use `takeIf` which "is like `filter` for a single value" ([takeIf() and also() - What's New in Kotlin 1.1 - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#takeif-and-also)):

```
repository.findByUID(request.userId).takeIf { !someCondition }?.let { service.run(...) }
```

Kotlin 1.0 does not define `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`/`takeIf`, etc. for nullable types but you can easily define your own function. e.g.:

```
inline fun <T> filter(value: T?, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T? {
    return if (value != null && predicate(value)) value else null
}
```

Example usage:

```
filter(repository.findByUID(request.userId)) { !someCondition }?.let { service.run(...) }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hoped for the built-in solution but I guess I need to build it myself :)

Comment: You may be able to make it built-in: https://kotlinlang.org/contribute.html

Comment: Ideologically Kotlin's `null` is very different from `Optinal`. It has  no business having `map` and `filter` IMO

Answer (score 1):

I would go without extra libs nor extension functions with this construct:

```
?.let { if (someCondition) null else it }
```

After aplying this construct on the code sample from the original question, it would look like:

```
fun handle(request: Request) {
    repository.findByUID(request.userId)
            ?.let { if (someCondition) null else it }
            ?.let {
                service.run {
                    /* ... */
                }
            }
}
```

Or at least it looks OK, compiles and have same types in my codebase after defining `Request`, `repository`, `findByUid` etc. :-)